# java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1 when using Cassandra timestamp column

Tags: java, jdbc, cassandra

I am using JDBC to query Cassandra. I have Cassandra 3.0 and java 1.7.0_101. I am unable to query with timestamp column. Below is my query:

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
Date startDate = Date.valueOf("2016-01-22");
Date endDate = Date.valueOf("2016-01-25");

pstmt = con.prepareStatement("select host_id,date_filter from btc_hourly_by_em where host_id = ? and date_filter >= ? and date_filter <= ? order by date_filter;");

pstmt.setInt(1, 1);
pstmt.setDate(2, startDate);
pstmt.setDate(3, endDate);

ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
```

Where host_id is of type int and date_filter is of type timestamp. The query works if I just host_id column in my select.
If I add date_filter column, due to type timestamp it gives me error as:

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
```

Can anyone help how can we deal with Cassandra timestamp with JDBC. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

if you set date use jdbc then parse to java.sql.Timestamp or java.sql.Date if you need only date without time

```
pstmt.setDate(2, new java.sql.Timestamp(startDate.getTime()));
```

Comment: You are saying setDate while working with Timestamp in the parameter....Dont you think its incompatible?

Comment: I have modified the setDate to setTimestamp, it still gives the same error....not working

Comment: A JDBC driver must support `setDate` on a `TIMESTAMP` column, and do the necessary conversions.

Comment: No Its not allowing me to use setDate on a Timestamp. It tells me "Incompatible types: Timestamp cannot be converted to Date"

Comment: Anyways I need a date to be set there....My main issue to deal is the date_filter column...How do I deal when doing select date_filter.....where date_filter is working fine....